# About HTML element position

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

i'm new at HTML, CSS. I'm trying to create a web-page with Dreamweaver.

Right now i have only 3 things in my page. A h1 header which is center aligned, a paragraph and a list.

I placed the paragraph and the list exactly at the center of the page in Dreamweaver live browser by positioning with "px". But the position is completely missed-up in Firefox and different in Chrome. Even the header is not in the middle which is center aligned. When i re-size the window the list stays fixed but header and paragraph moves according to the window size.

Please explain whats happening here and how to solve it. Again, i'm very new in this!

Thanks...

This my HTML file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My web page</title>
<link href="mycss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<h1>Welcome!</h1>
<body>
<nav id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="url">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="url">About Me</a></li>
<li><a href="url">Importent Links</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<p>About Me</p>
<p>About Me</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my css file:

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    display: block;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #202020;
    list-style-type: none;
}

p {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: 202020;
    top: -2em;
    position: relative;
    left: -19em;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    position: relative;
    left: 22em;
    top: -2em;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    border: 1px none #000000;
    position: static;
}
a:link {
    color: #77AED5;
}
a:hover {
    color: #418CC5;
}
a:visited {
    color: #6D4AFB;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/txZ5K/

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: You'll want to edit your original question and add your code there between `<pre></pre>` tags.

Comment: how to post HTML code here? my code gets parsed while writing here...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow! If you want to get a good, helpful answer, please post what you have tried to far.

Comment: Thanks! :)
i have posted my code in the question...

Comment: You have an h1 before body, put it afterwards

Comment: For one, you need to move the h1 down inside the body.

Comment: Added a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/txZ5K/

Answer (score 0):

Middle is relative. You can't specify a constant for this purpose, because every device and screen has its own dimenesions, and what is right in one is wrong for the other. 
what you can do is for example set `Position:relative`, `margin-left:auto`, `margin-right:auto` for example. or add `<center>` tag, depending on your exact case. if you post the code we might be able to help more.

**EDIT**

After posting your code, I will invite you to study some CSS, especially [positioning](http://learnlayout.com/position.html) ,[display](http://careers.societegenerale.com/), and float.
note that when you set `position:relative`, with `left` and `top` values it will become attached to this fixed place and not dynamic.

This is an edit to your code [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8R6hr/). don't forget to refer to the links provided for more information ;)

 Good luck

Comment: I'm just giving examples, he said the positions was in "px" which means it is fixed! maybe I'm wrong, but I think it is a point worth mentioning any way

Comment: When you write your code, highlight it and click the small icon with a tooltip of  `code`.
Or open this website JSFiddle.net, write you code, click save, copy the link and add it to your question!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a case where `position` is not how you want to solve this. Instead, using `margin: 0 auto` on your paragraph block should align it in the center of its parent width. The `li`'s are not what needs centering. You would be best off setting the CSS of the parent `ul` to `display: block; margin: 0 auto;` to center the list.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

HTML

```
<h1>Welcome!</h1>
<nav id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="url">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="url">About Me</a></li>
<li><a href="url">Importent Links</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<p>About Me</p>
```

CSS

```
* {
    text-align:center
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    display: block;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #202020;
    list-style-type: none;
}

p {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: 202020;
    position: relative;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

ul li {
    display:inline-block;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px none #000000;
}

a:link {
    color: #77AED5;
}

a:hover {
    color: #418CC5;
}

a:visited {
    color: #6D4AFB;
}
```

fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/txZ5K/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/txZ5K/1/)